# Create a Javascript table that we can see

Tags: javascript, html-table

I would like to create a table that is entirely generated by Javascript; however I never did that and I searched a lot on the internet and I don't get how its supposed to works! For example I would want a 3 row and 4 columns table that would display when loading the page with information I would choose to put in it.

Comment: look into generating html using something like jquery

Comment: I would want code and not generator like jquery

Comment: Well there are multiple ways you can do this, either just append a string like `<table><tr><td>123</td></tr></table>` using `innerHTML` or you can create elements with `creatElement`, either way if you want help you have to post some code that you have tried

Comment: Why do you need javascript if you you know all the dimensions? Seems like you can just use html. When asking general questions please make sure you explain what business problem you are solving.

Comment: Please explain the bigger picture. For the record, all you'd need to do is use a function like innerHTML to add an HTML table to the page, like writing anything else with Javascript.

Comment: a javascript library like jquery will save your sanity when trying to get things to work the same accross browsers, and you get a sane way of working with html using javascript. makes this task trivial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the code that you need...

```
var arr = new Array(2);// numbers of columns
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    arr[i]=new Array();
}


arr[0] = new Array("a", "b", "c");//first column
arr[1] = new Array(1,2, 3);//second column

document.write('<table border="1">');

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    document.write("<tr>");
    for (j = 0; j < arr[0].length; j++) {
    document.write("<td>"+arr[i][j]+"</td>");
    }
    document.write("</tr>");
}
```

you choose the imput

Comment: thanks for your help! This is what I mean!I have little questions tho: 1- could it be possible to create 6 table with different numbers of columns without writing 6 time this code?  2-could it be possible to have for example table 2 float beside table 1,and table 3 under table 1,table 4 under table 2,etc..  3-would it be possible to change color of character and font-size of words? thanks again

Comment: Yes only make the code like a function... and return the code, and insert in a div